# DIR() function gives run time error 52 with wild card combinations in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a code to automate a report. Part of that automation is to go to share point site open up a file based on wild card section and follow on with the code.

I am using DIR() to return the exact file name based on wild card combinations.

It works fine most of the time but at some specific triggers it runs into run time error 52 right at the line where DIR() is being called.

Specially when called through VPN or when the macro is run from the email attachment of excel macro file.

I have to manually run that DIR() by removing the wildcard combination and actually relacing it with the exact file name to get it working again or else it would not move.

Need help with making it more stable or consistent. Can FSO solve my problem here and how?

Mentioning the code which runs into the error:

```
Public Cmbval As String
Public actwbk As String

Public Sub Report()

Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim Cmbval As String

Select Case Cmbval
      Case Is = "Dec-15"
      myPath = ("\\wbcspaces@SSL\my\teams\")
      myFile = Dir("\\wbcspaces@SSL\my\teams\Rptnm2015-12-*.csv*")

      If (myFile = "") Then
      MsgBox "No file found"
      UserForm1.Show
      Exit Sub
      Else
     'Do something
      End If
      End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a40dd49-ba7c-4d41-ad07-c39fc2575217/runtime-error-52-when-using-dir-function?forum=accessdev), which might help you

> After much trial and error, I was finally able to determine that
>   offending strFilenames (which are derived from
>   Mailitem.ConversationTopics) had one or more tab characters (Ascii 9)
>   which are forbidden when using either the Dir or Kill statements.  I
>   had alread run code to remove any other disallowed characters from
>   filenames, so it took a while to figure out that this was even an
>   option.
>
> Here's the code I used to fix this by putting spaces in the place of
>   the tab characters:
>
> ```
> strFilename = Replace(strFilename, Chr(9), " ")
> ```
>
> Since then, the code has run smoothly.